# Google Analytics URL regex code

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I am setting goal conversion for my site links which are dynamic in Google Analytics

https://www.learningandthebrain.com/Online-Register/CONF-103/Submit

example of the dynamic links is above 
here the number after CONF- keeps changing and I want to create final URL for my goal

I have to enter the regexp expression to match the site link Online-Register/CONF-103/Submit

Answer (score 3):

If only the number after CONF changes, something like this should do the trick:

```
(.*)learningandthebrain\.com/Online-Register/CONF-(\d+)/Submit
```

This is pretty much as basic as it gets, so I would advice you to look into regular expressions in your free time. When learning regular expressions I have found this tool indispensable: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ - it allows you to easily check if your regex works as expected.

Edit:
The regex **should not** include the *www* part of the domain, because then it will only match requests coming from it and ignore requests from http://learningandthebrain.com. Actually I am pretty sure that even the "catch all" (.*) expression at the beginning can be omitted.

Also, forward slash escaping is not required with google analytics.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of efficiency finish Crafty_Shadow's regex

```
https:\/\/www\.learningandthebrain.com\/Online-Register\/CONF-(\d+)\/Submit
```

(I know this would better be a comment but I still don't have the rank to do it)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following regex:

```
/Online-Register/CONF-(\d+)/Submit
```

Note that the domain is not part of the Page attribute and won;t match if you include it in the regex. Just include the path.

I'd also enable the **ignore case** flag if you are using a webserver that makes no distinction between uppercase and lowercase like IIS.